# Explicit type checking for function parameters in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have a function type:

```
type Func = (param1: string, param2: number) => Promise<void>;
```

I want to validate functions using this type. But TS only throws error when the type is incompatible but not when the parameters are not present. Example:

```
const f1: Func = async () => {}; // need error here
const f2: Func = async (param1: string) => {}; // need error here
const f3: Func = async (param1: number) => {}; // TS throws error here only.
```

Comment: `f1` and `f2` _are_ valid `Func`s, both of them can be called `fX("", 0)` perfectly happily. Even if they declared both parameters, you can't force the implementation to _use_ them, so what's the point?

Comment: There is no type `Func` which works the way you want. You *could* write some kind of generic helper function so that `check(f)` only works if `f`'s arguments are known to be "exactly" `[string ,number]`, but [that's not how TS works](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#comparing-two-functions).  See the linked q/a for more info.